# How do you apply a Scale Translation to a DrawingContext?

Tags: wpf, drawing, drawtext

I have a `Canvas` with a scale translation applied in XAML.  Using `DrawingContext` I draw lines on the `Canvas`. I now need to add text to the screen.  I thought with formatted text I could apply a translation, but neither Formatted Text or `DrawingContext` accepts `RenderTransform`.  How do I apply a scale translation to the text so it will counter the scale translation of the canvas?

```
 ftext = New FormattedText("N", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, face, Me.DBFontSize, FalconDataBlock.Foreground)
 context.DrawText(ftext, .TargetLineInfo.EndAsWinPoint)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most UI apps, instead of using a DrawingContext, the right thing to do might be to add a child TextBlock to the Canvas, and change the TextBlock's RenderTransform.

However, assuming you have a good reason for using a DrawingContext, you could use [DrawingContext.PushTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushtransform.aspx) to push the transform you need (scale, translation, etc.), just before you invoke DrawText. Use [DrawingContext.Pop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pop.aspx) to restore the prior state after you're done with DrawText.